Explicit solution of a linear matrix equation
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be an unknown matrix.

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a known matrix
$B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a known matrix
$Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a known matrix
$q \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar, and it is known, too

I have the following linear equation for $X$, where all the quantities except for $X$ are known:
$$ A^TAXBB^T +q X = Y $$
Let's assume that $A$ is full column rank, and $B$ is full row rank, so that $A^TA$ and $BB^T$ are invertible. How can I solve it? I have no experience with matrix equations.
EDIT: I found the question on Twitter, as an example of a question which the OpenAI model o1 would fumble, and I was curious about the actual answer. Unfortunately, I've never solved matrix equations, so I didn't know where to start. The Twitter user only said that it could be solved without vectorization, but other than that, they didn't add details.

Writing $Y=C$ and again $A$ for $A^TA$ and $B$ for $BB^T$, we arrive at the Sylvester equation for $X$, i.e.,
$$
XB+qA^{-1}X=A^{-1}C.
$$

@user1551 this is really neat! If I'm not mistaken, this works because 1)$\forall A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $AA^T$ is symmetric, thus orthogonally diagonalizable, and 2) $SX'D$ is simply $s_{ii}x'{ij}d{jj}, \forall i, j$. Correct?

@user1551 it's a really simple solution, and I feel like a simpleton for not thinking of it :-) why don't you rewrite it as an answer? BTW, I think that, since $A$ is of full row rank and $B$ is of full column rank, this implies that $s_{ii}\neq0,\ d_{jj}\neq0\ \forall i,j$. Do you agree? This might help with the compatibility condition you wrote. It's still not enough...

(contd.)...because we could have $s_{i'i'}=-1, d_{i'i'}=1$ for some $i'$ and then we would get $-1+\delta_{i'i'}=-1+1=0$. But it would at least "fix" all the off-diagonal terms, since $\forall i\neq j, \ s_{ii}d_{jj}+\delta_{ij}=s_{ii}d_{jj}+0=c$ with $c\neq0$. What do you think?

@user1551 $A^TA$ and $B^TB$ are positive definite (instead of semidefinite) because they're invertible, right? You're correct that I didn't state what $q$ is, because I don't have information on that. I don't think that prevents you from writing an answer, though. You can say that if $q\geq0$, then the linear system has a unique solution, while if it's negative, the solvability of the system will depend on whether there are any couples $(i,j), \ i\neq j$ such that $s_{ii}d_{jj}=-q$, or if $\forall i\neq j, \ s_{ii}d_{jj}=c_{ij}\neq -q$.

When I have an equation to solve, I try to state it with as few variables (knowns or unknowns) as possible.  Here the terms $A^TA$ and $BB^T$ could be replaced by an $m\times m$ positive semidefinite symmetric matrix $G$ and an $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $H$ respectively.  They cannot both be positive definite unless $m=n$, which you've implied is false without saying which is greater.

In a similar vein we should perhaps eliminate the scalar $q$ from the problem.  You say you don't know e.g. whether $q\ge 0$, but it suffices to consider cases $q=1,0,-1$ (with $q=0$ being an especially stark simplification).  Yes, your Readers could tackle this for you, but typically this is a problem that you the OP came across and you are in the best position to say which if any of these cases is of greatest interest (or indeed already solved).  It might be that the Twitter user had in mind arguing that consideration of rank of (say) $Y$ suffices to prove no solution exists.

As mentioned by Dietrich Burde in his comment, this matrix equation belongs to the family of Sylvester / Lyapunov equations.
It is usually handled with the help of "vectorization". Since matrices form a vector space, you may choose a basis and rewrite a matrix $X$ as a column vector $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ by isomorphism, because  $\Bbb{R}^m \otimes \Bbb{R}^n \cong \Bbb{R}^{mn}$ basically.
In consequence, the linear operator $L$ defined by $LX = A^TAXBB^T + qX$ acting on $\Bbb{R}^m \otimes \Bbb{R}^n$ becomes $\mathcal{L} = B^TB \otimes A^TA + q$, where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product, so that the problem $LX = Y$ is translated as $\mathcal{L}\operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(Y)$, which you can now solve as a standard equation from linear algebra.
Now, as any linear system, the solution will greatly depend on $\mathcal{L}$, mainly on its invertibility, which itself depends on the considered matrices $A$ and $B$, so that the solution may be unique or not, if it exists.
As a final note, let's highlight that the said solution may display the following closed form,  for suitable $A,B$ and $q$ :
$$
X = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{-(n+1)}(A^TA)^nY(BB^T)^n
$$

Those who are accustomed to working with matrices won't know what you mean by $+q$ in your $\mathcal{L} = B^TB \otimes A^TA + q$; you should probably write that as $qI_{mn}$ (or something like $q\text{id}$ if you really want to stick to the operator formalism) given the likely background of the asker.
